# Regular expression. Find function name in php

Tags: php, find, expression, syntax-highlighting

I'd like to write regular expression syntax for finding php function name:

For example:

```
public function _c_Def()
{

}
```

and I like to get:

```
_c_Def
```

What I tried:

```
/function[\s\n]+(\S+)[\s\n]*\(/
(?:^|\n)function ([^\s]+)
```

But every time I miss something

Comment: Your regex `function[\s\n]+(\S+)[\s\n]*\(` seems to work : https://regex101.com/r/tQmEa6/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP Reflection API to get all methods in the class instead of just parsing it by regexp.

```php
$class = new ReflectionClass('Namespace\YourClassName');
$methods = $class->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php